# Tkinter GUI without repeating code

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, optimization, tkinter

been struggling a while with the finishing touches of my program. I figured someone might be able to help out.

Basically, my program consists asks the user which out of 4 companies it wants to display information about, using 4 buttons.

```
class CompanyAnalysis(tk.Frame):

    def displayfunction(controller, j):
        return lambda: controller.show_frame(j)

    company_choice = ["AnalysisCompany1", "AnalysisCompany2", "AnalysisCompany3", "AnalysisCompany4"]
    company_name = ["Company1", "Company2", "Company3", "Company4"]

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        header = tk.Label(self, text="Which company to analyze?")
        header.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, fill="x")

        for i,j in zip(company_name, company_choice):
            button = tk.Button(self, text=i, command=displayfunction(controller,j))
            knapp.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, fill="x")
```

That is basically the class for my company choices. However, my GUI being built the way it is, i currently have 4 IDENTICAL classes for the frames displaying company information. They look as follows:

```
class FAnalysEricsson(tk.Frame):


def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    text = tk.Message(self, text=companylist[0].fundamental())
    text.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, fill="x")
```

Where companylist is a list of objects, where i call the method fundamental which returns the information about the company. How do i design my GUI without repeating my code for each company? I was thinking maybe a toplevel window, like some sort of function (instead of the displayfunction) which when i press a button opens a new window displaying the information for the correct company (index of the companylist).

Please do not hesitate to ask me to clarify anything, kind of hard to explain without posting the entirety of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Create only one class, pass the index to `companylist` to the `__init__`method.

```
class FAnalys(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, cmp_index):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        text = tk.Message(self, text=companylist[cmp_index].fundamental())
        text.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, fill="x")
```